# Convert a CSV of strings into a Python array

Tags: python, csv

I need to convert a list of strings from a CSV file into a Python array.

The CSV list is very simple, they all follow the same format of a letter + space + 5 numbers, and are all stored in column 1.

| Column A |
| --- |
| C 26588 |
| X 14255 |
| F 12251 |

I intend to plug these into an API post request and the input array needs to be in the following format.

```
["C 26588", "X 14255", "F 12251", ....etc]
```

The below is the code I'm trying to use.

```
import urllib.request
import os
import json
import pandas as pd
import csv

output_list = []
data = pd.read_csv("path.csv")
data.head()
output_list = str(data['col1'].values + ", ")
print(output_list)
```

With the above code I'm getting the below result.

```
['C 26588, ' 'X 14255, ' 'F 12251,']
```

Comment: Do you want an array as result, or a comma-separated string? I'm confused about `str(data['col1'].values + ", ")`

Comment: the API only accepts input in the above format so each part number needs to be within "" and separated by a ,
The str is really an old bit from an earlier method I tried, where I was doing a for loop for each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already using `pandas`, you can convert the `pandas` column directly to a list with the following method:

```py
output_list = data['col1'].tolist()
```

The `pandas` [`tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html) will take the underlying `numpy` array of the specific column, and will call the numpy [`tolist`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) method.

Comment: This works like a gem. Can't believe it was this simple.
I was under the impression that a list needs to be built with a .append

Answer (score 1):

Here are several ways to convert CSV cells into a Python array with double quotes around the elements:

Method 1: Using csv module and string manipulation

```
import csv

with open('path.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    output_list = []
    for row in reader:
        output_list.extend(f'"{value}"' for value in row)

print(output_list)
```

Method 2: Using pandas and to_json

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path.csv')
output_list = df.to_json(orient='values')[1:-1].replace("'", '"')
print(output_list)
```

Method 3: Using numpy and tolist

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('path.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=str)
output_list = data.tolist()
output_list = [f'"{item}"' for item in output_list]
print(output_list)
```

Explanation:

Method 1:

- Reads the CSV file using the csv module.
- Iterates through each row, adding each value to output_list with double quotes around them.

Method 2:

- Reads the CSV into a pandas DataFrame.
- Converts the DataFrame to JSON with orient='values', which gives a list of lists.
- Removes the outer square brackets and replaces single quotes with double quotes.

Method 3:

- Uses numpy.genfromtxt to read the CSV as a NumPy array of strings.
- Converts the array to a list using tolist.
- Adds double quotes around each element.
- All three methods will produce the desired output: